# Finding a system of equations whose solution set is the walls of a 1×1×1 cube?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find a system of equations whose solution set is the walls of a 1×1×1 cube?

I know I need 6 variables, one for each wall. 
I know this is a unit cube.
I know I need to restrict the ranges of the variables,  but I don't know how. 
I was told my equation system might not be linear.

I don't know what my solution set should look like. 
I don't know if my equation is simply the surface area of each individual square.

Any tips and direction would help. Thanks.

Comment: $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)=1/2$

Comment: @Rahul:  That will get a solid cube, not the walls.

Comment: @Ross:How would I get the walls? Is there an equation I might have missed in high school geometry?

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} \left(|x|-\frac12\right)\left(|y|-\frac12\right)\left(|z|-\frac12\right)=0\\ \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}=\frac12\end{array} \right.$$

Comment: I cannot use "max" notation in my linear algebra course.

Comment: @Mike Well then just use the formula $$\max\{a,b\}=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}2,$$ twice, by noting that $\max\{x,y,z\}=\max\{\max\{x,y\},z\}$, to come up with an expression which wont use the $\max$ notation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if the cube is centered on the origin, you need $x$ to be $\pm 1/2$, same for $y$ and $z$

Comment: Ross, I appreciate the hint, but I don't understand why my x, y, and z need to be those values.

Comment: I was picking a particular $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cube that is easy to specify.

Comment: How do I define this constraint?

Comment: Can you write an equation that has only the solutions $x=1/2, x=-1/2$? The cube consists of points $(1/2,y,z)$ with $|y| \le 1/2, |z| \le 1/2$ and five other sides.

Comment: No, I have to come up with a "system of equations" where the "solution set is the walls"

Comment: wouldn't it be ideal to use a unit cube?